# Space Complexity (Auxiliary) for long code

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, switch-statement, space-complexity

Whenever we calculate extra space, we do not consider an input as part of calculation. Lets say we need an algorithm to print a digit to word-equivalent like 1 as "One", 2 as "Two" etc.

One way of doing this would be mapping each digit to its word equivalent.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "One");
.....
map.put(Integer.MAX_VALUE, "Something equivalent");
```

then have a function to return the word. This would consider to have O(N) extra space for storage.

My question is what if we write a function as such

```
public printDigit(int n) {
     switch(n) {
        case 1:
          return "One";
        ...
        case Integer.MAX_VALUE:
          return "Something equivalent";
     }
}
```

Normally, we dont consider usage of code space to be extra space? I am not used to that logic as I never encounter it before. So would we call this algorithm O(1) extra space since we are not having additional data structure to store;

Comment: Normally we consider one algorithm which works for all possible input sizes. In this case the size of the algorithm doesn't really matter because it is negligible for very large input sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If compiler decides to store the switch-cases in a jump table, the space complexity won't be `O(1)` anymore, as the implementation would be similar to a map in C++ or hashmap in Java. Instead it would be `O(N)`.

Other options available to a compiler is to do the linear search or binary search on the provided cases. In all these option, it would be mandatory to store each of the switch-cases in some form of container. Space complexity again would be `O(N)` in all those cases.

Above all, the `switch-statement` are more preferred over `if-else` for the readability. But, using `map` in the code can provide brevity and better maintainability.